# what does mean and standard deviation in random_normal in tf.compat.v1.random_normal() mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

Still I’m a little confused with random_normal() parameters (mean, stddev). What really does mean, stddev in random_normal mean?

```
(tf.compat.v1.random_normal([3, 128], mean=6, stddev=0.1, seed = 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above line of code tries to initialize  a tensor of dimension `[3, 128]` with random values drawn from a gaussian (normal) distribution (bell curve) which is centered at (`mean`) 6 and which has a standard deviation (`stddev`) of 0.1 (indicating the "spread" or "deviation" of values around the mean 0.1). The random seed `seed` is used to generate the same set of random values for the tensor across multiple runs of the code to ensure consistency across results. A random seed generates the same set of random values drawn from a particular distribution across machines.

More references:
 1. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/normal?version=stable
 2. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Comment: i got it , thanks , one more question , does a pre-trained model (FaceNet weights) are efficient for face recognition in real time research ?thanks

Comment: Yes, the pre-trained model would be helpful.